# Possible to remove section number and page number from TOC?

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, appendices

I would very much like that the the appendix sections of the Table of Contents doesn't have a section numbers, dots, and page numbers. If I do the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{section}}
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Appendix}
\section*{Another Letter} \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Another Letter}
\end{document}
```

then the section "Another Letter" is left aligned, so it doesn't look like the  others.

**Question**

Is it possible to have "Another Letter" styled the same way as normal TOC entries, but just without section number, dots, and page number?

Comment: There is an error, it should be `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Another Letter}`

Comment: What about sections before the appendix?

Comment: @egreg They should be normal and unaffected.

Comment: @SandraSchlichting Should `\section{Appendix}` in the text receive a number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know whether this really answers your question. Basically, I patch the `\appendix` command to suppress numbering of sections; then it also issues some commands to be written in the `toc` file to change the behavior from that point on. The double `\unexpanded` trick is for avoiding several `\protect` in front of macro names.

As far as I know, leaders are off for section titles in the `article` class to begin with, so there's no need to act on `\cftdot`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\appto\appendix{%
  \setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \unexpanded{\unexpanded{%
      \cftpagenumbersoff{section}%
      \setlength\cftsecindent{\cftsecnumwidth}%
    }}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\section{This has the section number also in the TOC}


\appendix
\section{Appendix}

\section{Another Letter}

\end{document}
```

[image]